# Column names reassignments using concatenated paste vectors

Tags: r

I have a data frame with column names like this (it is the output of a statistical test):

> ```
>   [1] "p_val"    "fdr"      
>   [3] "p_val"    "fdr"
> ```

Of course I would like to rename column names giving incremental numbers in order to distinguish all p_val and fdr etc. 
The desired output will be for example: p_val_1, p_val_2, p_val_3, .... and so on and equally for the other column names. I tried to use the following:

> ```
>  p_val = paste("p_val ", 1:17, sep = "_") 
>  fdr = paste("fdr", 1:17, sep = "_")
> ```

for all the names but I don't know how to concatenate them. I would avoid to sort the columns because without a character or numbers that distinguish for example among p_vals, I'm afraid that the original order could be broken and I will be no more able to go back to it. Can anyone help me please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be the inbuilt function `make.unique`

```
make.unique(colnames(data))
```

Comment: Also you can specify `sep` if you want to use `_` instead of `.`